# How to sort file names by specific part in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have lots of files in my build folder and I am trying to sort them by using sort command.

The structure of the files are like that:

name - version - 'v' - build date

> xxx-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-01-05.log
>   xxx-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-02-05.log
>   xxx-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-03-05.log
>   xxx-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-04-05.log
>   xxx-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-05-05.log

if we assume that version string will be stay in 3 digit, sorting them is easy. What if I add different versions like 2.1 or 2.0.0.2 here ? I need a result like this:

> xxx-2.1-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-05-05.log
>   xxx-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-04-05.log
>   xxx-2.0.0.2-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-03-05.log
>   xxx-2.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-02-05.log
>   xxx-2.0.-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-01-05.log

Comment: Are you sorting by date or by version number?

Comment: firstly by version of course. but in the second part, same versions must be sorted by date.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ cat file
xxx-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-04-05.log
xxx-2.0.0.2-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-03-05.log
xxx-2.1-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-05-05.log
xxx-2.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-02-05.log
xxx-2.0.-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-01-05.log 

$ sort -V -r -t- -k2,2 < file
xxx-2.1-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-05-05.log
xxx-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-04-05.log
xxx-2.0.0.2-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-03-05.log
xxx-2.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-02-05.log
xxx-2.0.-SNAPSHOT-V2014-07-10_18-01-05.log
```

**Note:** Some implementations of `sort` do not support `-V` option...

Explanation:

- -V : Version sort
- -t- : Split into columns with delimiter '-'
- -k2,2: Sort by field 2 & only 2
- -r : reverse sort (based on your expected output. Remove this flag, if not required.)

Comment: Sorry, I had added output of `sort` command without `-r`... Corrected.

Comment: This is sorting by the date stamp. The OP seemed to indicate he wanted to sort by version number.

Comment: anishsane, thank you for your answer. But if i dont understand wrong, you made this sorting by taking date part of string. What if i release an older version near now ? For example current release 2.1 but i released 2.0.2

as @EtanReisner said.

Comment: Aah! then my earlier answer (posted in comment & deleted later) was correct... Based on first code section (with all versions same) I thought you explicitly want to sort by date.